# Remembering Selections in ExtJS Grid with Paging On

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid

I have the following example available:

```
Ext.onReady(function(){

    var myData = [
        ['3m Co',71.72,0.02,0.03,'9/1 12:00am'],
        ['Alcoa Inc',29.01,0.42,1.47,'9/1 12:00am'],
        ['Altria Group Inc',83.81,0.28,0.34,'9/1 12:00am'],
        ['American Express Company',52.55,0.01,0.02,'9/1 12:00am'],
        ['American International Group, Inc.',64.13,0.31,0.49,'9/1 12:00am'],
        ['AT&T Inc.',31.61,-0.48,-1.54,'9/1 12:00am'],
        ['Boeing Co.',75.43,0.53,0.71,'9/1 12:00am'],
        ['Caterpillar Inc.',67.27,0.92,1.39,'9/1 12:00am'],
        ['Citigroup, Inc.',49.37,0.02,0.04,'9/1 12:00am'],
        ['E.I. du Pont de Nemours and Company',40.48,0.51,1.28,'9/1 12:00am'],
        ['Exxon Mobil Corp',68.1,-0.43,-0.64,'9/1 12:00am'],
        ['General Electric Company',34.14,-0.08,-0.23,'9/1 12:00am'],
        ['General Motors Corporation',30.27,1.09,3.74,'9/1 12:00am'],
        ['Hewlett-Packard Co.',36.53,-0.03,-0.08,'9/1 12:00am'],
        ['Honeywell Intl Inc',38.77,0.05,0.13,'9/1 12:00am'],
        ['Intel Corporation',19.88,0.31,1.58,'9/1 12:00am'],
        ['International Business Machines',81.41,0.44,0.54,'9/1 12:00am'],
        ['Johnson & Johnson',64.72,0.06,0.09,'9/1 12:00am'],
        ['JP Morgan & Chase & Co',45.73,0.07,0.15,'9/1 12:00am'],
        ['McDonald\'s Corporation',36.76,0.86,2.40,'9/1 12:00am'],
        ['Merck & Co., Inc.',40.96,0.41,1.01,'9/1 12:00am'],
        ['Microsoft Corporation',25.84,0.14,0.54,'9/1 12:00am'],
        ['Pfizer Inc',27.96,0.4,1.45,'9/1 12:00am'],
        ['The Coca-Cola Company',45.07,0.26,0.58,'9/1 12:00am'],
        ['The Home Depot, Inc.',34.64,0.35,1.02,'9/1 12:00am'],
        ['The Procter & Gamble Company',61.91,0.01,0.02,'9/1 12:00am'],
        ['United Technologies Corporation',63.26,0.55,0.88,'9/1 12:00am'],
        ['Verizon Communications',35.57,0.39,1.11,'9/1 12:00am'],
        ['Wal-Mart Stores, Inc.',45.45,0.73,1.63,'9/1 12:00am']
    ];

    // example of custom renderer function
    function change(val){
        if(val > 0){
            return '<span style="color:green;">' + val + '</span>';
        }else if(val < 0){
            return '<span style="color:red;">' + val + '</span>';
        }
        return val;
    }

    // example of custom renderer function
    function pctChange(val){
        if(val > 0){
            return '<span style="color:green;">' + val + '%</span>';
        }else if(val < 0){
            return '<span style="color:red;">' + val + '%</span>';
        }
        return val;
    }

    // create the data store
    var store = new Ext.data.Store({
        proxy: new Ext.ux.data.PagingMemoryProxy(myData),
        remoteSort:true,
        sortInfo: {field:'price', direction:'ASC'},
        reader: new Ext.data.ArrayReader({
            fields: [
               {name: 'company'},
               {name: 'price', type: 'float'},
               {name: 'change', type: 'float'},
               {name: 'pctChange', type: 'float'},
               {name: 'lastChange', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'n/j h:ia'}
            ]
        })
    });

    // create the Grid
    var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
        store: store,
        columns: [
            {id:'company',header: "Company", width: 160, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'company'},
            {header: "Price", width: 75, sortable: true, renderer: 'usMoney', dataIndex: 'price'},
            {header: "Change", width: 75, sortable: true, renderer: change, dataIndex: 'change'},
            {header: "% Change", width: 75, sortable: true, renderer: pctChange, dataIndex: 'pctChange'},
            {header: "Last Updated", width: 85, sortable: true, renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('m/d/Y'), dataIndex: 'lastChange'}
        ],
        stripeRows: true,
        autoExpandColumn: 'company',
        height:320,
        width:600,
        frame:true,
        title:'Sliding Pager',

        plugins: new Ext.ux.PanelResizer({
            minHeight: 100
        }),

        bbar: new Ext.PagingToolbar({
            pageSize: 10,
            store: store,
            displayInfo: true,

            plugins: new Ext.ux.ProgressBarPager()
        })
    });

    grid.render('grid-example');

    store.load({params:{start:0, limit:10}});
});
```

How would I go about remembering and reading the selections made on each page?

I don't want to include check boxes if I can.

Any help would be fantastic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use a mixed collection to build up a collection of record.  Wherever your selection event happens, you can read in the selection and add it to the mixed collection.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Ext.utils.Cookies class and the selection/deselection events in the SelectionModel to record which rows on what pages are selected. You'd also have to hook into the paging and or the load event of the store to reapply the selections when you change pages.